# Brother MFC 240C will not print but shows job as completed

Tags: usb, printing, brother

I'm using a USB connected Brother MFC-240C printer with Ubuntu 12.10. I installed the printer with the printer drivers found online with the Printers tool. However, when I perform a print operation, the print queue says Job completed when nothing happens at the printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a little searching, I found this article: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1483951 I went into Ubuntu Software Center and installed these two packages:

```
brother-cups-wrapper-bh7
brother-lpr-drivers-bh7
```

After uninstalling the old setup, the new installation appears to work fine.